# In Mongoid, how do I transfer an embedded document to a different parent?

Tags: embed, mongoid

I am using the following code below, but I would prefer not to have to delete/copy.  I used to be able to change the parent ID, but that doesn't exist for embedded documents in Mongoid/MongoDB

```
def move(new_parent)
  if self._parent != new_parent
    copy = self.dup
    self.delete
    new_parent.items << copy
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is the embedded documents are stored as attributes inside your parent documents - they don't have parent_ids, since they are actually part of their parent (hence, 'embedded'). As such, the only way to reparent them would be to clone & delete - as you've done.

You could probably cut your method down by one line, but that's about it.

```
def move(new_parent)
  unless new_parent.id == parent.id
    new_parent.items << self.dup
    self.delete
  end
end
```